# How to have a Razor page without any layout in Blazor 8

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

In Blazor .Net 8 Server-Side (WebApp) how can I have a Razor component without any layout?
In .Net 7 I Could have a .cshtml page that was just empty and have app.MapFallbackToPage to control the routes to get to that page.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

Define a layout called `NoLayout`:

```cs
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

@Body
```

And apply it to  pages

### Option 2

You can code it so navigation stays within the Blazor SPA.

First an attribute to identify pages that you want to render without a layout:

```cs
public class NoLayoutPage : Attribute { }
```

Add it to say `Weather`:

```cs
@page "/weather"
@attribute [NoLayoutPage]

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather</h1>
//...
```

Layouts are applied to routes in `Routes`, so we can add some logic there to detect pages with the attribute and render them directly using the `DynamicComponent`.

```cs
@using System.Reflection
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        @if (UseLayout(routeData))
        {
            <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
        }
        else
        {
            <DynamicComponent Type="routeData.PageType" />
        }
    </Found>
</Router>

@code {
    private bool UseLayout(RouteData routeData)
    {
        TypeInfo typeInfo = routeData.PageType.GetTypeInfo();
        var obj = typeInfo.GetCustomAttribute<NoLayoutPage>();
        return obj is null;
    }
}
```

I don't know how you'll navigate back, but that wasn't in the question.